# Zf2 Child Route Matching do not work

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The goal is to have two routes.

1. domain.de/wordWithMinFourLetters
2. domain.de/wordWithMaxThreLetters
3. domain.de/stackoverflow
4. domain.de/ch

Route 1 default action is business
Route 2 default action is countries

The Problem:

The Route 2 is always executed, and i dont know why. 
What is the mistake in my Route Config?

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'application' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'index'
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'business' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => ':business',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'business' => '[a-z]{4,10}'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'business'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'countries' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => ':countries',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'countries' => '[a-z]{2,3}'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'countries'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'clear' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/clear',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'clear'
                )
            )
        ),
        'sitemap' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/sitemap',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'sitemap'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You have a constraint on `slug`, which I think should be `business` / `countries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace some constraints

```
  'application' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'business' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:business',   // <--- update
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'business' => '[a-z]{4,10}' // <-----
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'index', // <--- update
                        'action' => 'business'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'countries' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:countries', // <--- update
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'countries' => '[a-z]{2,3}'  // <-----
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'index', // <--- update
                        'action' => 'countries'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

Comment: thanx for you assists. If i change it, than i receive a  error-router-no-match. Have updated my Route config, maybe i have an error?

If i change the "slug" than i receive a error if i want the route match with 

$sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()
                        ->getMatchedRouteName();

Comment: Thomas your my hero :D. Works perfect.